# Doctrine getRepository errors

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony5

I have problem with authentication via jwt:

```
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
      {
        try {
          $credentials = str_replace('Bearer ', '', $credentials);
          $jwt = (array) JWT::decode(
            $credentials,
            $this->params->get('jwt_secret'),
            ['HS256']
          );
          return $this->em->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneBy([
              'username' => $jwt['user'],
            ]);
        }catch (\Exception $exception) {
          throw new AuthenticationException($exception->getMessage());
        }
      }
```

Using this function, and while entering valid credentials, I'm getting this error:

> Credentials check failed as the callable passed to CustomCredentials did not return \u0022true\u0022.

I thought maybe in return function, `getRepository()` wants my repository of user entity. I passed parameters:

```
getRepository(UserRepository::class)
```

but I'm getting a different error:

> The class \u0027App\UserRepository\u0027 was not found in chain configured namespaces App\Entity

**Edit 1**:
I thought that maybe the `getRepository()` parameter should be passed as string but that returns this error:

> Class \u0027User\u0027 does not exist

**Edit 2**:
UserRepository.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordUpgraderInterface;

/**
 * @method User|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method User|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method User[]    findAll()
 * @method User[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository implements PasswordUpgraderInterface
{

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }


    public function upgradePassword(PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface $user, string $newHashedPassword): void
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', \get_class($user)));
        }

        $user->setPassword($newHashedPassword);
        $this->_em->persist($user);
        $this->_em->flush();
    }

    // /**
    //  * @return User[] Returns an array of User objects
    //  */
    /*
    public function findByExampleField($value)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->andWhere('u.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
    */

    /*
    public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?User
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->andWhere('u.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }
    */
}
```

and User.php Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")
 */
#[ApiResource]
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->roles = array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function getEmail(){
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email){
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getUsername(){
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username){
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getPlainPassword(){
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($password){
        $this->plainPassword = $password;
    }

    public function getPassword(){
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password){
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getSalt(){

        return null;
    }

    public function getRoles(){
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials(){
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how your repo & entity looks like (no need for properties & methods) ?

Comment: sure! ill edit my post give me second! edit1: Done added repo and entity

Comment: Does adding repo and entity help by any chance or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a link to your Repository class.

Edit your `@ORM\Entity` annotation with:

```
use App\Repository\UserRepository;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")
 */
#[ApiResource]
class User implements UserInterface
{
```

Comment: Hi, fixed by your idea, it seems it work becouse i get now new error :D. To be precise: The \u0022App\\Entity\\User\u0022 entity has a repositoryClass set to \u0022App\\Entity\\UserRepository\u0022, but this is not a valid class. Check your class naming. If this is meant to be a service id, make sure this service exists and is tagged with \u0022doctrine.repository_service\u0022 but i think ill be able to get it by myself. But if you have any ideas im open to them!

Comment: If you replace it by:
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")

Does it work ?

Comment: no i get same error as on start: Credentials check failed as the callable passed to CustomCredentials did not return \u0022true\u0022

Comment: It seems to be a different issue than the one I answered for. Have you tried dumping `$jwt` to see if you had what you want in `$jwt['user']`, also try dumping the result of `$this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $jwt['user'],]);` to see if you really had a user ?

Comment: Well, dumped both of them, $jwt['user'] indeed has user "test" and dumped also $this->em... and also got this user XD screen for preview https://imgur.com/a/8qcag9p

Comment: Then it mean your repository issue has been fixed since you managed to get your User. Do not hesitate to upvote & validate the answer and post another question with your new question (concerning your AuthenticationException even though you got the appropriate user). Let's not try to fix your entire application in comments under another question.

Comment: Well than, still HUGE really HUGE thanks to you my man. You have made my day a little bit better, any chance of me finding you on discord/slack(Of course if it's up to you) ?

Comment: I do not use either and I'm not that comfortable sharing my socials. I do, however, check questions on **StackOverflow**, so I guess I will see you there :p

Comment: Well than, im still very grateful for your help, if you are still interested in this topic heres next part xd: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835409/authenticationexception-even-though-i-got-the-appropriate-user